# JQuery Drag & Reorder

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have an image upload script that batch uploads loads of images.

I want a page where the admin user can go in and re-order these images easily. Is there a sort of click and drag and re-order JQuery plugin? I then want to read the order and assign a weight value to each.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the jQuery UI [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin.

If you give each draggable image a unique ID you can trivially read the list of images back to find out their current order.